# Qlikview statistics box

Tags: qlikview

I use in my project a statistics box with min, max and avg functions, everything works fine in desktop mode. If I select a value in my statistic box, data are filtered using the value selected (As I want).

Using WebView in desktop mode works also.

After deploying the project on qlik server and access the project, using Firefox or IE nothing happens selecting value in the statistics box.

Is there a trick to make statistics box "clikable" in web mode ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have you tried it with chrome?

Comment: Same with Chrome, nothing happend. I readed that we can't filter on expression value, but as it works in dekstop mode I thought it would work after deploying.

Comment: what version are you using - QV Nov 17 SR4 have some web fixes...

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the statistics box, but I've just tried it and it works in AJAX.

Which QV version is the server running?

Did you try with a basic QVW file to test it?
Just add the test script and try with a simple chart, statistic and selection box)